# Set that does not contain its supremum

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I am wondering, if a set does not contain its supremum, does this imply that the set is infinite? For example, say $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ has a supremum $a$ such that $a\notin A$. Does this imply the set is infinite? This tells us the set does not contain a maximum, but I am not sure about my other statement.

Comment: the open interval $0 < x < 1$ does not contain its supremum

Comment: Let's see, a finite set of reals does contain its maximum, so, yes

Comment: @WillJagy Then yes, if the set does not contain its supremum it is infinite.

Comment: It is true for you example but in general is false.

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase your question as "do finite sets contain their supremum?" which is indeed true, as the supremum of a finite set is its maximum element.

Comment: @Sam.  That is true only if the set is linearly ordered.